# Excel table with formulae to static table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am testing the result of many automatic report from a database that are outputted as tables on excel sheets.

in order to have quicker response the data sent from the db is raw and calculated by formulae on the excel sheet once recovered.

I need now to compare the results of said formulae with another report, and I wanted to do it by copying two similar reports results into yet another excel cartel and comparing some cells.

Ex:

```
     A     B     C      D     E     F     G
1 | Avg |     |      |     |     |     | Avg1 |                   |  Test  |
2 | 2.5 |     |      |     |     |     | 2.51 |                   | =A2=G2 |
```

Where A is the column of the first report and G is the column of the second report.

The problem is that `Avg` is a calculated cell too, so I can't copy the value onto another sheet.

As you can see I want the data on the same sheet for quicker reading and testing, so I would like to know if there's a way to "print" an excel sheet statically onto another sheet, so that the calculated cells would not be the result of a calculation but a simple value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you paste the formula onto another sheet, instead of just using a regular paste, you can right click and should have the option to "paste values" as highlighted in graphic below:

[image: paste values example screencap]

Alternatively, you can use the keyboard shortcut CTRL + V to paste in the formula then hit CTRL again to open the paste menu followed by "v" to select the "paste values" option.

If you need to perform this several times you can use excel's "Quick Access Toolbar" If you look at the very top of Excel, you can see its Quick Access Tool Bar. By default, it should have the "save" icon, and undo and redo icons.

1. Then at the end there should be a down arrow where you can select additional actions.
2. Choose the "more commands" option
3. In the "choose commands from" drop down menu select "all commands"
4. Scroll down the alphabetical list until you find the "Paste Values" command
5. Highlight it and click the add button

Now the button will appear on the top bar. You can use a keyboard shortcut ALT + # where the # represents the order of the command. For example, with Excel's default quick access toolbar, ALT + 1 would save, ALT + 2 would undo, ALT + 3 would redo, etc.